# Memory exception when initializing QtFont

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to use the new fonts from OpenCV 3.3 that are required by `cv::addText()`. I am trying two different examples:

```
cv::QtFont font8 = cv::fontQt("Times", 1, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 
cv::QT_FONT_NORMAL, cv::QT_STYLE_NORMAL, 0);
```

It fails with a `cv::Exception` at at memory location. It is unable to perform the memcpy.

The second variant is something similar to:`CvFont fontB = cv::fontQt ("Times", 30, cv::Scalar (255, 255, 255), CV_FONT_BOLD);`

This one can be found in different tutorials but it doesn't work because there it can't convert a qt font to a cv font. Even the most basic example from the official documentation fails. I freshly installed OpenCV from its respective website and I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Is there any other method of initializing a QtFont? Does OpenCV need to be compiled in a special manner?

Comment: Were Qt and opencv built using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Did you try simply cv::QtFont font8 = cv::fontQt("Times")
 this would use all standard parameters so at least you can exclude a wrong parameter.